# How to Calculate Summary Statistics For Distance Bands in R

Tags: r, distance, sf, st-distance

I currently have a shapefile with tourism data by district for the country of Jamaica, but I would like to try and also obtain for each district the average amount of tourism activity in districts whose centroids fall within 5,10 and 20 miles from the centroid of the district. Is there a straightforward function to do this in R, or do I need to first calculate a distance matrix and then for each district calculate the average of tourism values for districts that fall less than the specified distance away?

Comment: Within 5, 10, 20 miles from what? The centre of each district? From the edge of each district? From a set of points? How big is each district? What happens when a 20 mile radius cuts through a district?

Comment: From the centroid of each district to the centroid of other districts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of this problem is probably the `st_is_within_distance` test function.

Load some Jamaican boundaries and convert to centroids:

```
adm3 = st_read("./geoBoundaries-JAM-ADM3.shp")
admc = st_centroid(adm3)
```

Get the list of neighbours of each centroid within 10km:

```
within_km10 = st_is_within_distance(admc, admc, 10000)
```

Each element of this is the row numbers of centroids within 10km:

```
> within_km10[[23]]
  [1]   3   4   5   6   9  11  12  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
 [19]  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42
 [37]  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  57  58  59  60  61
 [55]  ....
```

Let's add some random tourism factor as a column in the spatial data:

```
admc$tourism = sample(1:nrow(admc))
```

Then to total up, apply over the list by summing that tourism value for each row in the list:

```
tourism_10km = unlist(lapply(within_km10, \(v){sum(admc$tourism[v])}))
```

Which gives something like:

```
> tourism_10km
  [1] 10338 11830 18463 28392 23794 27196  7901  8735 33686 16681 39130 52210
 [13] 14236 43283 43746 52733 52526 51136 51390 50165 51502 53226 53229 52896
 [25] ... [etc] ...
```

which you can then add as a column to your original polygon spatial data if you want:

```
adm3$tourism_10km = tourism_10km
plot(adm3[,"tourism_10km"])
```

[image]

The pattern here is because the "tourism" number is random but when the districts are small there's more of them within the 10km distance, so there's on average more to add up!

For your case, convert your 10 mile band to kilometres (?16) and repeat for your distances - you can make a loop over distances if you need.

Comment: This is great! Thank you! I tried to put your solution into a function and then use lapply on that function in order to loop over years of data, but the unlist(lapply(..)) portions yield list of NAs for some reason. Would you happen to know why this is or should I make a separate question?

Comment: So you have tourism data for each district for different years and you are trying compute the tourism within distance bands for different years? Sounds like some subset or indexing problem... Debug as much as you can and then ask a new Q, and you might need to link to sample data or create some o we can reproduce the error...

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks!